# What does this script means

Tags: bash, shell, command-prompt

I am new to scripting and I found following expression in a script.

```
if [ -d $_path ];then
```

could someone help me to understand what does -d $_path means inside if statement?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Note that cmd.exe isn't DOS. It's a command interpreter, since about 1998 for Windows. And bash isn't DOS as well. DOS was a 16 bit OS, afaik, not a shell. Windows called a desktop icon "DOS-prompt", which started a shell, mostly compatible to cmd.32 from the interface, but not compatible to Bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [man test](http://ss64.com/bash/test.html):

```
-d FILE
    FILE exists and is a directory
```

Comment: neither does the test brackets in the questions example, nor the "bash" tag. :-)

Comment: Oh, I didn't mentioned them. :) Pardon.

Answer (score 2):

It's a test for whether _path is a directory.

Note bash and DOS are two entirely different things.

Answer (score 1):

It checks whether the value of `_path` is a directory. Note that `_path` is a variable and the `$` is the get-value-of operation (sort of); it is not looking for a folder called `$_path`.

As an example:

```
> mkdir dir
> touch file
> ls
dir/  file
> _path=dir    # set the variable `_path`
> if [ -d $_path ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
yes
> _path=file
> if [ -d $_path ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
no
```